# calculate the number of sessions for each different user in rdd in spark cluster

Tags: python, session, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I have a rdd, working in spark cluster --in rdd, each has the format (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 ), a1 keeps userid, a2 keeps timestamp, I need to calculate the number of sessions for each different user. each session is a continued time period that is equal to or more than 50 mins, how can I calculate it by using timestamps?for example ( user001, 1:12:01, xx, xx, xx ), ( user001, 1:30:12, xx, xx, xx ), ( user001, 2:06:01, xx, xx, xx ),...

I should exclude ( user001, 1:30:12, xx, xx, xx ), right? if user001 starts at 1:12:01...

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, I could convert timestamps to real time display like 1:30:12 etc( ignore date in simple way, later consider the date info ), one way is to use the first time value and 50mis to calculate the following values, y=( 1*60+30 -x )%50 , here x is each following values, if y = 0, don't include x in the first session, find the first y1 that is 1, use the x1 ( y1 = ( 1*60+30 -x1 )%50 ) is to calculate for the second session, continue the process...but how to use mapreduce to do quickly?

Comment: can you provide a small reproducible example please?